# Ubuntu display adapter problem (Nvidia vs Xorg Nouveau)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors

I am wondering if there would be possibility to get the "best" from both worlds:

With Nouveua drivers I can use external displays, but when my laptop goes to suspended mode, it will get page fault and never recover without reboot in recovery mode.

With Nvidia drivers the system is stable, but is not able to use external monitors.

Is there a possible solution to this problem, or should I just try ArchLinux or move back to using Windows with Ubuntu VM?

Comment: The version is 16.04